# How to display two plots together?

Tags: plotting

I have two plots

Edit: I am making this more tractable after reading the guide

```
Plot1 = Plot[{Sin[t]}, {t, -10, 10}]
Plot2 = Plot[{Cos[t]}, {t, -10, 10}]
```

How can I display these together in the same plot?

Comment: Two ways: `Plot[{Sin[t], Cos[t]}, {t, -10, 10}]` (so put multiple functions together into a single plot), and `Show[{Plot[Sin[t], {t, -10, 10}], Plot[Cos[t], {t, -10, 10}]}]`.

Comment: FWIW, searching this site for "two plots" (or something similiar) will yield several related questions.

Comment: thank you that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be

```
Plot1 = Plot[{Sin[t]}, {t, -10, 10}]
Plot2 = Plot[{Cos[t]}, {t, -10, 10}]
Show[Plot1, Plot2]
```